# Double.ToString() with limited number of characters

Tags: c#

Say I have some doubles:

```
12
10145
-0.00000000001455744121548787
100122455471000245487.05
```

I want to be able to converts them to strings with at most 9 characters. The output would be something like:

```
12
10145
-1.45e-11
1.0012e21
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

For the two first numbers, I do not want the output to be:
    1.2e1
    1.0145e4

Comment: What are the rules for which format to use?

Comment: `1.456e-11` has a different sign than `-0.00000000001455744121548787`

Comment: [This](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) tutorial may be of use, but I'm not sure it handles the character `e`

Comment: Your last two example outputs are 9 characters each... I think that you are going to have to write yourself a function that looks at the magnitude of the number and decides on the best way to format it based on whether it needs scientific notation or not and how many decimal places there is room for.

Comment: @Oded: the rules are: as long as your double fits in n characters, outputs the exact value, otherwise use the scientific nototional so that it fits in n characters

Comment: I think he means 7 significant figures

Comment: @HansZ: what people call significant figures is the number of digits before the "e" in scientific notation. I want the total number of characters to be 7

Comment: @d--b: you said "your integer" in that comment... did you mean double or shoudl the output only ever be an integer?

Comment: @Chris: sorry I meant double and 9 digits.

Comment: It's pretty much a human way of looking at numbers. You would write 15265.5 but 1.6514e23

Comment: Trouble with human way of looking at things is that you need to specify it exactly for a computer. I really think you need to just work out all the rules and write a function. For example if the number is `0.000001234567` should that be `0.0000012` or `1.2346e-6`? I'd suggest finding a maximum and minimum range for the absolute values and anything inside of those is done "normally" and anything outside in scientific notation. Then chuck a load of numbers in and see what ones come out in a way you don't like and modify as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to use `String.Format` for your formatting.

You would first need to check if you need to use scientific notation (i.e. if number is greater than 10^7, between -10^-7 and 10^-7), but the way you print out a number to be in scientific notation with at most 6 digits after the decimal is:

```
String.Format("0.0######e+###", myDouble);
```

Comment: it's not that bad a check, your check is basically if it's greater than 10^7, between -10^-7 and 10^7, or less than -10^7 then you format.